# resque-web command leads to an error while setting up Resque gem on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I`ve just watched this amazing railscast about [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque).And after I start redis server and launch workers with:

```
rake environment resque:work QUEUE="*"
```

I want to load the resque web-interface. After I run

```
resque-web -p 8282
```

this bug is raised:

```
C:\Users\makaroni4\free_frog\ffapi>resque-web -p 8282
[2011-06-21 19:04:13 +0400] Running with Windows Settings
[2011-06-21 19:04:13 +0400] Starting 'resque-web'...
[2011-06-21 19:04:13 +0400] trying port 8282...
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:187:in `daemon': daemon() function is unimplemented
on this machine (NotImplementedError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:187:in `daemonize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:108:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:77:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.16.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.16.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/resque-web:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/resque-web:19:in `<main>'
```

May be I miss some gem? Here is my configuration for resque:

```
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
```

I am using Windows for my rails development by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command

```
resque-web -p 8282 -F
```